# Write data read from database to binary file

Tags: c++, database, binary

I want to write the data I read from database to binary file. In the query I need to read a lot of data and some of them are `group_concat`. Now I want to write them into a binary file. The question is how can I define the size of them. At first I used `put()` but the result was wrong because `put` requires the type of `char` while `row[]` is `char*`. Then I tried `write` and defined the size by `sizeof(int)`*number of elements in group but it was still wrong. Please show me a way.

```
MYSQL_RES* res = GetDBManager()->Query("select ls.time, count(ws.id) , group_concat(wc.id) , group_concat(ws.SIGNAL_STRENGTH) , ul.LONGITUDE , ul.LATITUDE , ul.ALTITUDE  from user_location_scan ls, wifi_scan ws, wifi_cell wc, user_location ul where ls.id = ws.user_scan and ws.wifi_cell = wc.id and ls.time = ul.time group by ls.id order by ls.id");
    if (res == NULL) return false;

MYSQL_ROW row;

ofstream myFile("data.bin", ios::out | ios::binary | ios::app);

while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) {
    myFile.write(row[0], sizeof(char));
    myFile.write(row[1], sizeof(int));
    myFile.write(row[2], sizeof(int)*atoi(row[1]));
    myFile.write(row[3], sizeof(int)*atoi(row[1]));
    myFile.write(row[4], sizeof(double));
    myFile.write(row[5], sizeof(double));
    myFile.write(row[6], sizeof(double));
    //myFile.write(row[0], sizeof(row[0]));
    //myFile.write(row[1], sizeof(row[1]));
    //myFile.write(row[2], sizeof(row[2]));
    //myFile.write(row[3], sizeof(row[3]));
    //myFile.write(row[4], sizeof(row[4]));
    //myFile.write(row[5], sizeof(row[5]));
    //myFile.write(row[6], sizeof(row[6]));
    //myFile.put((char)row[0]);
    //myFile.put((char)row[1]);
    //myFile.put((char)row[2]);
    //myFile.put((char)row[3]);
    //myFile.put((char)row[4]);
    //myFile.put((char)row[5]);
    //myFile.put((char)row[6]);
    //myFile << row[0] << row[1] << row[2] << row[3] << row[4] << row[5] << row[6];

}
mysql_free_result(res);
```

Comment: What is `group_concat`?

Comment: ok let me show you my code

Comment: that's what i tried all this morning

Comment: Instead of using `sizeof()` try using `strlen(row[0]) + 1` to give the length of the string including the null terminator.

Comment: @Galik wow worked like a charm. thank you so so much. anyway can you give me some documentation you use about what you just said?

Comment: I've posted an answer I will be adding to it shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MySql function `mysql_fetch_row()` returns an array of null-terminated strings (character arrays). You can use `std::strlen()` to get the length of these null-terminated character arrays.

If you want to write everything out as strings into the file then it is sufficient to do something like this:

```
while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)))
    for(unsigned col = 0; col < 7; ++col)
        myFile.write(row[col], std::strlen(row[col]) + 1);
```

If you want to write the numeric columns as binary numbers (harder to make portable) then you need to convert the strings and write the values out differently.

**Much less recommended** is writing each record out in binary. This is very non-portable.

```
struct record
{
    // choose better column names
    char col_0[32]; // largest possible string
    int col_1;
    int col_2;
    int col_3;
    double col_4;
    double col_5;
    double col_6;
};

while((row = mysql_fetch_row(res)))
{
    record r; // store our binary values here

    //copy the string
    std::strncpy(r.col_0, row[0], sizeof(r.col_0));

    r.col_1 = std::atoi(row[1]); // convert the integers
    r.col_2 = std::atoi(row[2]);
    r.col_3 = std::atoi(row[3]);

    r.col_4 = std::atof(row[4]); // convert the floats
    r.col_5 = std::atof(row[5]);
    r.col_6 = std::atof(row[6]);

    // write the whole object out in binary (very non-portable)
    myFile.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&r), sizeof(r));
}
```

**And to read the record in again:**

```
// reading back

record r; // store our binary values here

if(myFile.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&r), sizeof(r)))
{
    // success, use the record here
    std::cout << r.col_0 << '\n';
    std::cout << r.col_1 << '\n';
    std::cout << r.col_2 << '\n';
    // ... etc
}
```

**NOTE:** Using binary is more complex, harder to get right, un-portable and generally to be avoided unless its an absolute requirement.

Comment: thank you very much. at first i intended to convert them into numeric types so it is easier to read later. but i think writing as string is still good because i can cast the right type to the data when reading them from the file, cant i?

Comment: @DucAnhNguyen Writing as strings is preferable because it very portable and network friendly. However I will post a method you can use to write everything out in binary but its very non-portable (even between versions compiled using different flags on the same compiler).

Comment: @DucAnhNguyen As you can see using binary is more complex, harder to get right, un-portable and generally to be avoided unless its an absolute requirement.

Comment: you are right. actually at the beginning i used JSON to avoid binary but my instructor asked me to use binary. i think he wanted me to know how to use different kinds. thank you once again and hope you have a nice day!